# Passing multiple rows of data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I pass multiple rows of data from one screen to the second one without overloading the values of the first data passed?

```
        onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => new orderpage(
                        '${widget.productName.toString()}',
                        '$total',
                        counter,
                        check_tandeef,
                        check_makwa,
                        sab8a)));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congrats on posting your first question. It would be helpful if you could update your question by adding some more information. The code you posted doesn't show the expected result / actual result of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your point, I'm not sure.

To pass values, you can use args in the Navigator and the use those values in your second screen.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Another way, would be using InheritedWidget class, so you can use the same instance of an object all across your widgets without being passing them by the context

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean you wan't to pass multiple sets of the same data to the next screen. You could do this by creating a class which holds all your params, and then pass a list to your Screen.

```
class myViewModel{
 String param1;
 String param2;
 int param3;
 bool param4;

 myViewModel(this.param1,this.param2,this.param3,this.param4);
}
```

Create the list and fill it with instances of the Class:

```
listOfParams = List<myViewModel>();
```

Pass the List:

```
onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => new orderpage( 
                     listOfParams
             )));
```